# bootstrap 4 checkbox click not working with javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

i am doing: on click on table row do table row add class `active` with javascript it's working, but now when i click on `checkbox` giving error.

[Here is Codepen live Link](https://codepen.io/scalescript/pen/JmOPQa)

here is Custom Code:

```js
$('.dashboard-table-tbody tr').click(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).children('td').children('div').children('input').prop('checked', false);
   }
   else{
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).children('td').children('div').children('input').prop('checked', true);
   }
  });
```

```css
.dashboard-table{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size:13px;
  line-height:15px;
  color:#8b8e8c;
 }
 .dashboard-table th{
  border:none;
  padding:8px 12px;
  font-weight:600;
 }
 .dashboard-table td{
  padding:12px 12px 12px 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .dashboard-table a{
  font-weight:600;
 }
 .table-checkbox-col-head{
  width:44px;
 }
 .table-checkbox{
  padding: 0;
  min-height: auto;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label{
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
 }
 .table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label:before, .table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label:after{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
 }
 .dashboard-table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #fafbfe;
 }
 .dashboard-table tbody tr.active {
  background-color: #f8f9fc;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm dashboard-table">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline2" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline2"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="p-l-0">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Size</th>
        <th scope="col">Upload at</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-right">Views</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="dashboard-table-tbody">
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline3" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline3"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="active">
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline4" type="checkbox" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline4"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline5" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline5"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline6" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline6"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline7" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline7"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline8" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline8"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: You could provide the actual code in the question. SO also allows you to embed the code to show a live example like in Codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the tr click triggering twice.

Here is the demo of changes.

```js
$('.dashboard-table-tbody tr').click(function(e) {

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).children('td').children('div').children('input').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).children('td').children('div').children('input').prop('checked', true);
    }

    if ($('.table tbody').find('input:checkbox:checked').length === $('.table tbody').find('input:checkbox').length) {
        $(".headerCheckbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(".headerCheckbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
    e.preventDefault();

});

$(".headerCheckbox").click(function(e) {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".table tbody tr").addClass("active");
        $(".table tbody tr input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(".table tbody tr").removeClass("active");
        $(".table tbody tr input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```css
.dashboard-table{
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size:13px;
  line-height:15px;
  color:#8b8e8c;
 }
 .dashboard-table th{
  border:none;
  padding:8px 12px;
  font-weight:600;
 }
 .dashboard-table td{
  padding:12px 12px 12px 12px;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .dashboard-table a{
  font-weight:600;
 }
 .table-checkbox-col-head{
  width:44px;
 }
 .table-checkbox{
  padding: 0;
  min-height: auto;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label{
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
 }
 .table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label:before, .table-checkbox .table-checkbox-label:after{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
 }
 .dashboard-table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #fafbfe;
 }
 .dashboard-table tbody tr.active {
  background-color: #f8f9fc;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm dashboard-table">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input headerCheckbox" id="customControlInline2" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline2"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="p-l-0">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Size</th>
        <th scope="col">Upload at</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-right">Views</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="dashboard-table-tbody">
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input checkBox" id="customControlInline3" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline3"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="active">
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline4" type="checkbox" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline4"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline5" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline5"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline6" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline6"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline7" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline7"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="table-checkbox-col-head">
         <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox defaultCheckbox table-checkbox">
          <input class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline8" type="checkbox">
          <label class="custom-control-label table-checkbox-label" for="customControlInline8"></label>
         </div>
        </th>
        <td class="p-l-0"><a href="#">File-Name.mp4</a></td>
        <td>137.3kB</td>
        <td>10/9/2018, 4:53:28 PM</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
```

Comment: Working Thanks. brother. i need also to click on `<head>` Name `Checkbox` to `checked` and add all `tr` class active, can you tell me how can i do it please? thanks in advance.

Comment: @hassan please take a look at updated code, FYI this is totally different question then you asked.

Comment: Thank you so much brother. :)

Comment: when i click on File Name so it's not going another page...?

Comment: filename url onclick not through me on link. :(

Comment: @hassan Please try yourself doing that, for hint you can read about `jquery not selector`